# export scrapy to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Is there a way to export scrapy data to a text file so that when the python script runs it generates a text file without having to go through the terminal to execute scrapy?

Example of code

```
class NameListSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'namelist'
    allowed_domains = ['namelist.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.namelist.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="post-outer"]/a'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'name': response.xpath('//div[@class="alt"]/span/span[2]/text()').get()
        }

# have added the below as an example
with open("file.txt", "a") as file: 
    file.write(name)
```

Comment: You want to execute the python code without going to the terminal?

Comment: To execute the python file which will then execute the spider and write to a text file. For example `python namelist.py` which will then execute the code which includes writing the data to a text file rather than `scrapy crawl namelist -o namelist.csv` (there is no text file output via scrapy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more than one way you can achieve this result.
If you want to run your project with `scrapy crawl` you can [configure feeds in settings](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#settings).
If you want to run it with `python your_python_script.py` you would need to pass the settings as well.
You could even export different items to different files. For that purpose, check out [this pipeline on github](https://github.com/patkle/scrapy-snippets/tree/master/Pipelines/MultiItem)

Now to run your spider using `python your_script.py` you would do something like this:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider

class NameListSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'namelist'
    allowed_domains = ['namelist.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.namelist.com']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="post-outer"]/a'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'name': response.xpath('//div[@class="alt"]/span/span[2]/text()').get()
        }

def get_settings():
    settings = Settings()
    settings.set('FEED_URI', 'file.txt')
    settings.set('FEED_FORMAT', 'csv')
    return settings

if __name__ == '__main__':
    settings = get_settings()
    runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)
    d = runner.crawl(NameListSpider)
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()
```